# Excel calculate SLA between dates for a 24 hour workday

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2007

I have the following formula that calculates the work hours between two dates with timestamps. However, the formula returns incorrect results based on my manual calculation.

The data is as follows:
Cell D2 = 1/11/2018  7:00:00 PM
Cell H2 = 1/15/2018  9:00:00 PM

My formula returns 46.00 hours rather than 32.00 hours.

> =24*(NETWORKDAYS(D2,H2)-1)-24*((MOD(H2,1)-MOD(D2,1)))

I feel its something simple that i am missing and appreciate the help anyone can offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> <sub>The data is as follows: Cell D2 = 1/11/2018 7:00:00 PM Cell H2 = 1/15/2018 9:00:00 PM</sub>

try,

```
=24*NETWORKDAYS(D2,H2)-24*((1-MOD(H2,1))+(MOD(D2,1)))
```

result: 50

5 hrs Thu, 11-Jan-2018
24 hrs Fri, 12-Jan-2018
21 hrs Mon, 15-Jan-2018

I don't know how you expected 32 hrs nor how you plan to deal with weekend or holidays on the start or stop dates.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your edits worked perfectly. And you are correct, i was expecting 50. I overthought and my counting got messed up lol.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this would be:

```
=(24*NETWORKDAYS(D2,H2))-HOUR(D2)-(24-HOUR(H2))
```

> `(24*NETWORKDAYS(D2,H2))` gets you the number of work days between two dates and multiplies by 24 to give you the number of hours. In this case 72
>
> `-HOUR(D2)` this subtracts the number of hours from the start date since they will not be part of your worked hours. In this case -19 hours
>
> `-(24-HOUR(H2))` this subtracts the remaining hours from the last day since they are after the worked hours. In this case -3 hours